# C - Linux module: wait_event_interruptible inside critical section

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm building a Linux kernel module that allows exchanging messages across threads. I think it is not clear to me what is meant by process and interrupt context. Within a kernel module when can we run in interrupt context?

In fact, I was wondering if `wait_event_interruptible` can be safely used inside a critical section implemented with `mutex_lock` / `mutex_unlock`.

Comment: "I was wondering if `wait_event_interruptible` can be safely used inside a critical section implemented with `mutex_lock` / `mutex_unlock`." - Yes, it is perfectly allowed to do so. It is allowed to "sleep" under mutex locked, and `wait_event_*` is one of the sleeping functionality.